# DELETE data from a table, joining through two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I'm working with some rather sensitive data, so I want to be ABSOLUTELY sure I am doing it properly.

I am trying to delete the rows in a table that are associated with another table

The only way to associate the table is to join through two other tables...

here is the exact query:

```
DELETE tt.Transaction_Amount, tt.Transaction_ID
  FROM ItemTracker_dbo.Transaction_Type tt
  JOIN ItemTracker_dbo.Transaction t ON tt.Transaction_ID = t.Transaction_ID
  JOIN ItemTracker_dbo.Purchase p ON p.Transaction_ID = tt.Transaction_ID
  JOIN ItemTracker_dbo.Item i ON i.Item_ID = p.Item_ID
 WHERE i.Client_ID = 1
```

As you can see, it ain't pretty.

I'm getting an odd error though through the MySQL query browser...

> Unkown table 'Transaction_Amount' in MULTI DELETE

I've tried reading the mysql manual and it seems like this should work to me... any one have any idea's?

Comment: You don't seem to be using the Transaction table you have joined with elsewhere in your query. Is this intentional?

Comment: Make sure you have backed up your data / database before you do a delete.

Comment: Is Transaction_Type a table? It looks like you're trying to remove 2 columns from a table rather than rows...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to delete rows from `tt`, not individual columns:

```
DELETE tt
  FROM ItemTracker_dbo.Transaction_Type tt
  JOIN ItemTracker_dbo.Transaction t ON tt.Transaction_ID = t.Transaction_ID
  JOIN ItemTracker_dbo.Purchase p ON p.Transaction_ID = tt.Transaction_ID
  JOIN ItemTracker_dbo.Item i ON i.Item_ID = p.Item_ID
 WHERE i.Client_ID = 1
```

Comment: You have to specify the tables to delete from, either with names or aliases, between `DELETE` and `FROM` in a multi-table delete

Comment: @md5sum: That's for multi-table deletes, but I too don't know if it makes a diff in this example

Comment: @DavidM Great answer and comment, solved my problem almost 3 years later =)

Comment: @Windle - good, love it when an old answer still helps people out.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is incorrect - you [don't reference columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) between the `DELETE` and `FROM`.  Use:

```
DELETE FROM ItemTracker_dbo.Transaction_Type tt
  JOIN ItemTracker_dbo.Transaction t ON tt.Transaction_ID = t.Transaction_ID
  JOIN ItemTracker_dbo.Purchase p ON p.Transaction_ID = tt.Transaction_ID
  JOIN ItemTracker_dbo.Item i ON i.Item_ID = p.Item_ID
 WHERE i.Client_ID = 1
```

To be sure you're deleting the correct stuff, I agree with wallyk that you should check the output of the SELECT statement that what is returned is what you want to remove prior to.  Otherwise, perform the delete in a transaction so you can roll it back if needed.

Comment: Don't think that will work - check my reply to your comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You should compose it initially as a query to return the rows of interest.  Once that's all debugged, then convert it into a delete.

Answer (score 0):

Check with select query and then before executing delete query on critical data get a backup of that table. so simple as if anything going wrong then you can at least backup.